# Difference in declaration Java

Tags: java, duplicates, declaration

I'm new to Java and I'm coding just for fun, and I'm wondering about this.

```
Set<Employee> employees1 = new HashSet<Employee>();
HashSet<Employee> employees2 = new HashSet<Employee>();
```

Is there any difference in those two declarations ? I mean like " behind the scenes " ?  I was looking for similar problem here, but I didn't find anything maybe because I don't know how to interpret the question in search field.

Comment: `Set` is an interface. `HashSet` is an implementation of that interface. If you say `Set`, you can swap out the HashSet for any other implementation (of Set) you want (at runtime).

Comment: Look up interitance/polymorphism. It should clear some things up for you.

Comment: And the main advantage of using first declaration is abstraction, which will give you the chance to switch Set implementation (to SortedSet for example) in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is an interface, where as [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is a class implementing that interface.

```
Set<Employee> employees1 = new HashSet<Employee>();
```

By reference variable `employees1` you can call **only those methods** of `HashSet` class which are declared in `Set` interface and overridden in `HashSet`.

```
HashSet<Employee> employees2 = new HashSet<Employee>();
```

By using `employees2` you will be able to call overridden methods of `Set` interface and `HashSet` class's own methods (which are not declared in Set interface.)

Comment: And the main advantage of using first declaration is abstraction, which will give you the chance to switch Set implementation (to SortedSet for example) in the future. (copied this comment to question itself)

Comment: @mulya nice point

Comment: Choosing to use an interface is like sending your future self a surprise gift.

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is an interface, while `HashSet` is one of its implementations.

If your variable is declared `Set`, it could have other implementations as value. EG:

```
employees1 = new TreeSet<Employee>();
```